# how to move files from ec2 instance to S3 as soon as it is created in a loop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have made a web scraper that downloads a bunch of PDFs. The script is basically a loop and downloads a PDF(~8 MB) per iteration. The total file size is estimated to be >300GB. I was thinking that instead of creating an instance with that much storage, why not put the PDFs in an S3 bucket as soon as they are downloaded.

I will be using a t2.xlarge ubuntu system. The loop is supposed to run for 2 weeks, so I believe it will be cheaper to use S3 bucket instead of buying extra storage for t2.

The thing is that the script downloads the PDFs in the /Downloads folder. I think I need to mount a bucket using s3fs? Then I will recursively copy the files in the Downloads folder and paste them in the mounted bucket, and then use `rm` to delete everything in the \Downloads folder. Is this the way to go is there a more straightforward way?

Any help or documentation link would be appreciated! Thanks!

Related posts:

- [How to move files from amazon ec2 to s3 bucket using the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396065/how-to-move-files-from-amazon-ec2-to-s3-bucket)
- [Move files from EC2 to S3 and then delete from EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514668/move-files-from-ec2-to-s3-and-then-delete-from-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do much simpler with AWS Lambda.

Create a trigger event with AWS Lambda. Then pull the pdf file and directly save it to S3.

> Cloud Watch Events (cron) --> Lambda --> S3

With this you pay only for the amount of time you run the code. No need to pay any fixed fee.

If you are a command line person only comfortable only with CLI, you can run the script to download file and save it to S3.

> curl "https://linktopdf/" | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/filename

You can just use a t2.small for this purpose.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The script I have made uses Selenium and Chrome. Will it work in a Lambda function?

Comment: You can run selenium and chrome under headless mode in lambda. More info can be found under, https://medium.com/clog/running-selenium-and-headless-chrome-on-aws-lambda-fb350458e4df

Comment: Thanks but I can't find a tutorial to do that